# Webpart Property Drop-down list allow edit value

Tags: kentico

When I set a webpart property control to drop-down menu with List of Options as the data-source and check "allow edit value", using name-value pairs gives the name instead of the value in the code behind.

Is this a bug or is there something that needs to be set in these cases?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop-down list is usually not meant to allow users to enter values, generally you want someone to pick from the options you offer them. The control generates output as HTML `<select>` tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

If you allow users to edit the values of the drop-down, it's not really a drop-down anymore, generated tags are changed to regular `<input>` tag and the "drop-down" functionality is ensured by a CSS style, so name-value pairs won't work for this option.

If you need to create a dropdown that would allow editing values while saving something else in the background you'll have to implement your own logic for this in a custom form control.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unfortunate part of the "Allow Edit Values" as whatever is typed is what the value actually is, so the value;pair doesn't really work in that case.

Although i can think of some ways to better code it (to check if the entry is found in the value;pair listing, in which case return the value, otherwise return the entry as the value), base functionality is this.